# Large problem with blueprint in Unreal Engine 5.1

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

### [Project input setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heAU6.png)
[Camera nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfi7g.png)

[and i wanna add some animations for my character... its optionally=)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl7nq.png)

---

I'm new in unreal engine! and I have big and bad problem...

- I just want to control my camera in the Y axis (pitch), and it's just not working...

Please do guide me with this!
Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked if InputAxis is called? Have you checked if the values are as expected?

Answer (score 0):

The adding of animations is a bit more difficult to explain in a single answer and I would suggest researching on the topic or reading the documentation on animation.
First of all the scale '1' on the y input would create a "inverted mouse" setting.
Second thing would be trying to see if the Mouse input gets registered in the first place. You could use a PrintString for this and hook it up to the output axis value of the mouse input event. Please answer with your results.